# A question about thermodynamic reversible process

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, work, reversibility

I am a new learner of thermodynamics, and I have a question in my assignment:

> Show that $W$ and $Q$ for an arbitraty mechanically reversible nonflow process are given by: 
>   $$W=\int VdP - \Delta(PV),\quad Q=\Delta(H) - \int VdP$$

I do not know how to prove it, and when to use $VdP$.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 2):

This is really a mathematical exercise on [integration by parts](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegrationByParts.aspx).

$W = -\int P dV = -(\Delta PV - \int V dP) = \int V dP - \Delta PV$

$Q = U - W = \Delta U - (\int V dP - \Delta PV) = \Delta U + \Delta PV - \int V dP = \Delta H - \int V dP$